# Docker tar not found on nvm install node step

Tags: node.js, docker, aws-lambda, node-modules

I'm trying to create a Docker container running node.js on Amazon Linux to allow native node modules to compile on machine in a suitable form for AWS Lambda.

I'm primarily following this tutorial on [The Polyglot Developer](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/12/deploying-native-nodejs-dependencies-aws-lambda/), but have also tried one on the [AWS Blogs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/). I am attempting to build the container with the following command in the Dockerfile's parent directory.

```
docker build -t amazonlinux-node8 .
```

Steps 1 & 2 complete succesfully but on step 3 throws the following error.

```
/root/.nvm/nvm.sh: ... tar: command not found
```

It then exits with the following message.

```
The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/bash -c "source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh; nvm install 8.10.0"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What changes do I need to make to fix this error?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash

RUN /bin/bash -c "source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh; nvm install 8.10.0"

CMD /bin/bash -c "source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh; nvm use 8.10.0"
```

I have tried the solution suggested on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613153/tar-command-not-found-in-dockerfile) by adding steps to download `tar.x86_64` but this fails and will not install on the `amazonlinux` image. I have seen another suggested solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179863/the-command-bin-sh-returned-a-non-zero-code-1), however it specifically relates to use of the `COPY` command in the Dockerfile which is not applicable to my file.

Comment: I’d just start my Dockerfile `FROM node:8`.  I would not try to use a version manager like nvm in a Docker image: you never need more than one version of Node in a single image and the setup is slightly tricky.

Comment: Thanks, I'd had the same thought as it seems like the obvious option. My doubt was that the `node:8` image would not be using a suitable OS to solve the compilation issue. If it does then these tutorials offer an absurd solution. In any case I have since discovered the `lambci/lambda:build-nodejs8.10` (https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda) which solves my issue perfectly.